# javascript inline script doesn't work after jquery import from cdn

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code:

```
<code><html>
<body><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">

alert("debug");

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And i don't know why the second script isn't loaded. I've also tried:

```
<html>
<body><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  alert("debug");

</script>

</body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
```

See a related posting on SO

**[Why don’t self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)**

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use self-closing `<script>` tags in HTML documents, they will break in IE. Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
```